# How to seed grasses correctly if the area has moss and lack of sun

Tags: lawn, grass, seeds, lawn-repair

I just bought a bag of seeds from Costco: Pennington Smart Blend

https://www.pennington.com/all-products/grass-seed/pennington-smart-blend

My lawn has many dead grass spots due to some plants being in places I didn't want them 2 weeks back. It also has mosses.

I raked them all to make the surface a little rough then spread the seeds down like the photos

[image]

[image]

[image]

Questions:

1. Did I spread it enough?
2. Should I put compost? Because there are some mosses?

Comment: did you soak the seeds for about 24 hours before spreading as that will help wake them up?

Comment: I did not. Am I screw? I am spraying water twice a day now. It has been 2 days.

Comment: you can do something like this with a large tarp to get the seeds to sprout, or wait for snowfall: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p7tN4ohZXfc

Comment: If you have moss , you do not have enough sun for most grasses.